# Uv map not loading correctly in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, uv-mapping

My uv map is loading like it's one side of a block:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    const grass = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Isaiah08-D/namelater/main/textures/blocks/grass.png' );
    
    
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:grass});
    ...

  var noise = new noisejs.Noise(Math.random());



    for (let x=0; x < 201; x += 10) {
      for (let z=0; z<201; z+=10) {
        //const chunk = getChunk(x, z)
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
        cube.position.x = x
        cube.position.z = z
        cube.position.y = noise.perlin2(x/100, z/100) * 100;
        cube.scale.set(10,10,10);
        blocklist.push(cube);
        scene.add( cube );
      }
    };
```

And you can find the uv map [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Isaiah08-D/namelater/main/textures/blocks/grass.png).
How do i get it to load so that each tile is one side:
[image]
etc.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The wrapping is absolutely correct. The bottom left is (0, 0) and the top right is (1, 1).  You are actually trying to wrap parts of the texture onto different sides of the cube. However, this is not a default behavior.

Comment: @Rabbid76 
I changed my comment. Does this clarify things more?